# Oracle Interval Bug?

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

I'm using this sql query:

```
select sysdate, sysdate - INTERVAL '6' month from dual;
```

But it is return: ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified.

Which is weird, because if I change the the number into 9, it is return the date (sysdate = 31/05/11 and the subtracted is 31/08/10). I'm also tried using different value: 1,3,6,8,11 also not working, but 2,4,5,7,9,12 are working.

From the numbers, I think it is because the resulting quert doesn't have 31 days for that month. Is this the expected behavior? Because in MySQL, I can use the query (select now() - Interval 6 Month;) to get the correct value. Is there any other way?

I am using Oracle 11.1.0.6

Comment: Probably it is better to not assume bugs directly!

Comment: As far as I know, this problem (bug? feature?) is actually defined in the ANSI standard so it may not just be Oracle that has problems with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sysdate,add_months(sysdate,-6) from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm just moving from MySql to oracle. So many different syntax to learn :)

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out that it's not a matter of add_months being the right syntax and the interval arithmetic being wrong. It's a matter of defining how YOU want to do your date arithmetic.

Answer (score 3):

It is the expected behaviour; see the sixth bullet [in the datetime/interval arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i48042) section of the documentation.

As Lisa says you can use [`add_months`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i48042), which has the opposite behaviour - which can also cause confusion sometimes. You need to decide which is most suitable for you.